# Поднятие элемента из под модального окна.

Tags: html, css, css3

При нажати на иконку с лупой появляеться модальное окно с поиском. А на месте иконки лупы появляеться крест. Все содержимое под модальным окном блюриться с помощью `filter: blur(1.5px);` не получаеться поднять иконку крест из под блюра(пробовал `z-index`). Если убрать блюр все работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно быть примерно так. На второй картинке я убрал блюр.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно вам поможет псевдо-класс `:not()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:not)). При наведение блюрится все, кроме кнопки.

```css
header {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  background:blue;
  padding:10px;
  color:white;
}

header:hover *:not(button) {
  filter:blur(2px);
};
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>Наведи мышь, чтобы заблюрить все, кроме кнопки</h2>
  <span>Какой-то текст</span>
  <div>Контент всякий</div>
  <button>Это, например, ваша кнопка</button>
</header>
```